# mui5 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')

Tags: material-ui

I copied this code from official example:https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
    import { StepConnector, stepConnectorClasses } from '@mui/material/StepConnector';
        const QontoConnector = styled(StepConnector)(({ theme }) => ({
          [`&.${stepConnectorClasses.alternativeLabel}`]: {
            top: 10,
            left: 'calc(-50% + 16px)',
            right: 'calc(50% + 16px)',
          },
```

but I get the error
*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')*

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your second line.
Change it to this:

```
import StepConnector, { stepConnectorClasses } from '@mui/material/StepConnector';
```